# access denied to the port COM just on windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows, serial-port

I develop in c#. I would like to use the com port, but it is always denied on windows 7.
The port is enabled on windows 8 and 8.1. I use a serial to usb converter ATEN usb to serial bridge.

I got this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: Access to the port 'COM10' is denied.

I opened the serialport just once in the code at the begining of the project. There is not another program what uses this port.
I tried to restart the computer and run the program. I tried to unplug and replug the port. It would had to worked.

I tried the PortMon to find what does use my serialport. 
The PortMon wrote "not connected", then I tried the ProcessExplorer to find the serial between the processes. I did not found.

How can I solve the problem. Why always use anything the serialport on windows 7?

```
public App()
        {
            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);


            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort
            {
                PortName = "COM10",
                BaudRate = 9600
            };


            bool a = serialPort.IsOpen;
            serialPort.Open(); //exception occours here
        }
```

[image]

Comment: High odds that another process actually *is* using the port.  Try stopping the Telephony service.

Comment: but how can I found it? I tried the PortMon. The PortMon writes not connected, then I tried the ProcessExplorer to find the serial between the processes. I did not found

Comment: i'm in same boat, seems like a permission problem buried deep? all of sudden on win7, works fine in win10.

Comment: ha I should've listened to Hans, stopping Telephony makes all the difference. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the Fax service, set it to Manual in services.msc

Thanks to Hans for the tip!

Edit: another thing you can do is turn off the fax call receive.
Open Windows Fax and scan, choose Tools/Fax Settings and uncheck "Allow the device to receive fax calls"

[image]